# Pandas - CSV to SQL database

Tags: python, sql, pandas, mariadb

I have now resolved the issues I was experiencing. Many thanks commenters. My amended and now functioning code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy_utils import *

#create engine and connect to DB
engine = create_engine("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/polution")
if not database_exists("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/polution"):
  create_database("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/polution")
else:
  engine.connect()

#create tables and define
metadata_obj=MetaData()
sites = Table('sites', metadata_obj,
        Column('SiteID',Integer, primary_key=True,nullable=False),
        Column('Location',Text(48)),
        Column('geo_point_2d', String(150)))
metadata_obj.create_all(engine)

#read in csv, set specific table-relevant dataframes, push to database
df = pd.read_csv("cleanedcropped_bristol-air-quality-data.csv", sep=",", parse_dates=["Date Time","DateStart","DateEnd"],low_memory=False)

dfsites=df[["SiteID", "Location", "geo_point_2d"]][:100]
dfsites.to_sql(name='sites',con=engine,index=False,if_exists='replace',)`
```

I'm really new to all this and I'm currently working on something that is stretching my skill and understanding so I'd appreciate some help please.

I have a large csv file that I want to read into a pandas data frame and then push the contents to an already created mariadb database made up of multiple entities. Currently, I'm trying to attempt this with the to_sql() function. Running the script seems not to actually push any data from the dataframe to the entity in the database as it remains empty after run.

FYI the dataframe contains multiple columns, only some of which I want to push to the relevant entity.

Any pointers greatly appreciated!

```
conn = sqlalchemy .create_engine("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306")  
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute(databse = "pollution")

sites= """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sites`
  (`siteID` INT(20) NOT NULL,
  `Location` VARCHAR(48) NULL,
  `geo_point_2d` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`siteID`))"""

cur.execute(sites)

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",", parse_dates ["DateTime","DateStart","DateEnd"],low_memory=False)

df.to_sql('sites', conn, if_exists='append',index=False)
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Please explain specifically what issues you are encountering instead of just "not having any luck".

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had qualified that in the sentence after when I described that to_sql() doesn't seem to be pushing any data to the entity in database

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors. Just an empty entity in my db

Comment: Can you set `echo=True` in `conn` so you can see what is the sql generated?

Comment: did you try to add- `conn.commit()` after the execute statement?

Comment: By the way, you shouldn't use `if_exists='replace'` if you want to define the table using SQL. That will replace the table with the one created by pandas. You probably want `if_exists='append'`.

Comment: Also how are you creating conn?

Comment: Amended my original post to reflect the above comments. Thanks for your feedback. The entity still is empty

Comment: Instead of `USE pollution`, specify it directly in the connection as `database="pollution"`

Comment: the connection should be a sqlalchemy engine I think. `conn = sqlalchemy .create_engine("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306")`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas but still nothing is being pushed. Above amended to reflect suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try to commit your execution after creating the table.

`cur.execute(sites)`

`conn.commit`

Comment: Thanks but didn't seem to change anything

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be failing because you are trying to insert columns that are not part of the schema as described in sites -> "DateTime","DateStart","DateEnd". If that's the case, include those columns in the sites string. Otherwise, you'll need to subset your data frame.

If you can't get this to work with the pd.to_sql() command, here's a workaround. You'll need to create a Table object. If it's an already existing database table make sure to set the 'autoload_with' = to your engine (which I think is 'conn' for you).

Convert the dataframe into a dictionary that is oriented as a list of records (a list of dictionaries), each row will be its own dictionary. Each key will be the column name, and the value will be the specific row value that corresponds with the column.

Then you can simply just insert the list of dictionaries into the database.

```
engine = sqlalchemy .create_engine("mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306")  
cur = engine.cursor()

cur.execute(databse = "pollution")

sites= """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sites`
  (`siteID` INT(20) NOT NULL,
  `Location` VARCHAR(48) NULL,
  `geo_point_2d` VARCHAR(150) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`siteID`))"""

cur.execute(sites)


df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", sep=",", parse_dates ["DateTime","DateStart","DateEnd"],low_memory=False)

# specify which columns you want, as a string, and within the double brackets.
df = df[['siteID,'Location','geo_point_2d']]

"""or if you have too many columns to manually put in, but have a specific range in mind.
this is telling pandas to get the first four columns
when you see this -> : -> it means start:stop """

df = df.iloc[,:4]

metadata_obj = MetaData()
records = df.to_dict(orient='records')

#note rather than creating a sql string you can also create the Table with a table object, checkout the sqlalchemy tutorial I linked

sites = Table('sites', metadata_obj, autoload_with =engine)



with engine.connect() as conn:
   conn.execute(sites.insert(),records)
```

I also think it would help if you read through the sqlalchemy-core [documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html). This tutorial will show you how to create a Table object with the columns you want.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive reply. I really appreciate your time.

I had noticed that the column mis-match was a problem and had already begun separating the data frame into smaller frames to match the requisite columns which has helped somewhat.

The difficulty I continue to have is that, when using the to_sql() function after creating the requisite table, I receive an error because the table already exists. This happens despite passing the if_exists='append' argument. I would like to understand why this happens if you have any thoughts on the matter?

Comment: I have now resolved the issue and everything is now running fine. My issue was caused by the if_exists='append' argument. Given the contents of the entities in my database, append is ordinarily fine. However, in the particular instance of my 'sites' entity and the allocation of primary keys, 'replace' was the right argument to pass.